# Slow to show Open / Save File Dialog in Windows with mapped Network Drives

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, mapped-drive, windows-shell

The issue is that if you have one or more mapped network drives and have not accessed them "recently" within your logon session, your first attempt to show Open/Save File dialog in ANY program will be slow, taking ~ 15-20 seconds.

I am aware of similar questions, however I am wondering if there is a solution that will actually let you "have your cake and eat it too":

- Network drives still show up in the dialog but are not "checked/queried" until you try clicking / expanding them.
- File dialogs show up quickly.

Strangely enough when you just open **My Computer** or **Explorer**, even though there are mapped drives, the window opens up immediately, so why does it have to be an issue for Open/Save File dialogs, which are part of the same Windows shell?

So, the question is: is there a way to retain those mapped drives for convenience and ease of use, but always have Open / Save file dialogs show up quickly just as Windows Explorer does?

Answer (score 2):

Try right-clicking the drive and choose "Disconnect" from menu.  Strange enough, it should know already that it's disconnected but doing this changes the drive's state (as you can see when you click "Properties") so I think this might be exactly what you're looking for - the item remains in the drive list but Windows will remember that it's disconnected and won't try to access it unless you open it again.  Well - *in theory* it works like that.  Even if the explanation is not accurate, I just seem to have fixed my open/save dialogs with this but it was kinda too easy to be true :)